# How to find the current revision that a working copy is in using TortoiseSVN?

Tags: svn, tortoise-svn

I have an old working copy of an SVN repository with 100,000 revisions. How can I find out what revision that working copy is in without modifying it? I'd prefer a GUI solution to this problem using TortoiseSVN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the **root of WC** in Windows Explorer (or any another shell):

- Properties - `Subversion` tab

[image: Subversion Tab]